# correct css for slide out left nav / image position in FireFox (all browsers)?

Tags: html, css, firefox

In firefox the slidein_btn starts too far right on load. only after opening and closing the slide menu does the image (in firefox) correctly go to the left side of the div.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<img id="imgSlideOut" src="images/slidein_btn.png" style="position: absolute; float: left; top: 50%; margin-left: -20px;"/>
<img id="imgSlideIn" src="images/slideout_btn.png" style="position: absolute; float: left; top: 50%; margin-left: 160px; display: none;"/>

<div id="slideMenu" style="display: none; float: left; border: 1px solid #929497; min-height: 600px; width: 160px;">
    slide out menu here
</div>
```

HTML/jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#imgSlideOut").click(function () {
        $("#slideMenu").show();
        $("#imgSlideOut").hide();
        $("#imgSlideIn").show();
    });
    $("#imgSlideIn").click(function () {
        $("#slideMenu").hide();
        $("#imgSlideIn").hide();
        $("#imgSlideOut").show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Any chance you can whip up a fiddle showing exactly what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layout isn't quite working properly as you are mixing float and absolute positioning and your div is not absolutely positioned.  Removing some of these styles will actually make it work in Firefox and other browsers.

```js
$("#imgSlideOut").click(function () {
        $("#slideMenu").show();
        $("#imgSlideOut").hide();
        $("#imgSlideIn").show();
    });
    $("#imgSlideIn").click(function () {
        $("#slideMenu").hide();
        $("#imgSlideIn").hide();
        $("#imgSlideOut").show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="imgSlideOut" src="http://placehold.it/15" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-left: -15px;"/>
<img id="imgSlideIn" src="http://placehold.it/15" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-left: 160px; display: none;"/>

<div id="slideMenu" style="display: none; border: 1px solid #929497; min-height: 600px; width: 160px;">
    slide out menu here
</div>
```

Comment: I might not be wrong if I say it is the same answer I provided earlier

Answer (score 3):

You can't use absolute positionning and `float` on the same element. Use `left` or `right` instead :

```css
#imgSlideOut {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 50%;
}
#imgSlideIn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 160px;
    top: 50%;
    display: none;
}
```